# 2-dim struct table

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010

In C, I can use the following form inside a method.

```
void foo() {
   struct {
      int val;
      int color;
      string desc;
   } ItemMap[] = {
      { 1, 2, "test"},
      { 2, 3, "test"},
   }

   // process tasks according to ItemMap.
}
```

If I want to do the same thing under C#, how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use anonymous types for that in C#:

```
var ItemMap = new[] { new { val = 1, color = 2, desc = "test" }, 
                      new { val = 2, color = 3 , desc = "test" } };

string description = ItemMap[0].desc;
```

This would however create a one-dimensional array of an *anonymous class* for you not a struct - also it is read only. If you specifically need a struct / value type that is mutable, you will have to declare the struct outside of your method.